# how to parse json body which is like a listed dictionary

Tags: json

i want to get access of "uuid" everytime,which is two times present in this code and also access to "cloud_uuid". the body is something like below:

```
{
"computes": [{
    "uuid": "110c607a-231c-4724-be7f-db5ed388158",
    "name": "9.4.98.33",
    "description": null,
    "version": "1.0",
    "type": "compute",
    "number_of_vms": 0,
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "provisioning_status": {
        "status": "COMPLETED",
        "started_at": "",
        "updated_at": "",
        "status_data": null
    },
    "health_status": {
        "status": "OK",
        "alerts": [],
        "updated_at": "2014-07-11T17:09:12.194000"
    },
    "compliance_status": {
        "compliance_reasons": null,
        "is_compliant": true,
        "updated_at": null
    },
    "run_priority_order": null,
    "created": "2014-07-11T16:01:32.837821",
    "updated": "2014-07-11T17:08:16.031838",
    "capability_categories": {
        "v": [{
            "name_key": "",
            "description_key": "",
            "version": "0",
            "hidden": t,
            "priority": 1,
            "name_nls": "",
            "description_nls": ""
        }],
        "monitoring": [{
            "name_key": "m",
            "description_key": null,
            "version": "1.0",
            "hidden": true,
            "priority": 100,
            "name_nls": "monitoring",
            "description_nls": null
        }],
        "scheduler": [{
            "name_key": "",
            "description_key": null,
            "version": "1.0",
            "hidden": false,
            "priority": 20,
            "name_nls": "",
            "description_nls": null
        }],
        "network": [{
            "name_key": "",
            "description_key": "",
            "version": "1.0",
            "hidden": false,
            "priority": 10,
            "name_nls": "",
            "description_nls": ""
        }]
    },
    "links": [{
        "href": "",
        "rel": "self"
    }, {
        "href": "",
        "rel": "bookmark"
    }],
    "cloud_uuid": "b603e16e-38a6-435e-9359-79c27fee93a",
    "operating_system_uuid": "70f605e7-6512-49b4-833c-b25d47823a4"
}, {
    "uuid": "7383f4a5-dc0a-420b-806c-abbd49c1655a",
    "name": "9.4.193.20",
    "description": null,
    "version": "1.0",
    "type": "compute"
```

could you help with below,i tried the code as answered in comment:
suppose body is "clouds" instead of "computes"
i tried for getting cloud_uuid with something like:`cloud_uuid = ((e['cloud_uuid']` for `e` in `dict['clouds'] if e['name'] == name_to_find), None)`
it throws error->

> cloud_uuid = ((e['cloud_uuid'] for e in dict['clouds'] if e['name'] ==
>   name_to_find), None) TypeError: 'type' object is unsubscriptable

Comment: What language are you coding in?? Can you format your JSON please?

Answer (score 0):

In python it is very simple:

```
[(e['uuid'], e['cloud_uuid']) for e in dict['computes']]
```

Edit:
It looks like I overlooked a pair square braces. Try:

```
[(_['computes'][0]['uuid'], _['cloud_uuid']) for _ in data]
```

Comment: i tried for getting cloud_uuid with something like:cloud_uuid = ((e['cloud_uuid'] for e in dict['clouds'] if e['name'] == name_to_find), None),,,it throws error->   cloud_uuid = ((e['cloud_uuid'] for e in dict['clouds'] if e['name'] == name_to_find), None)
TypeError: 'type' object is unsubscriptable